# neovim: display column number on the left of screen + make other ones a little bit transparent

Tags: numbers, neovim

I know how to display column number on the left of the screen (set number)

but idk how to make something like that:
https://image-is-random.me/VDD5OT4L (upload systems screensshot)

basicly i want to keep line where i am yellow and make other ones a little bit transparent

question nr.2 how to keep it for always, cuz powershell always load deafult settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
hi CursorLineNr guifg=#000000
```

to set the color of the cursor line number and

```
hi LineNr guifg=#000000
```

to other line.

Comment: thanks, but i have an issue my init.vim is not initializing at start (again) can u help me with that?

Comment: hmm sorry i don't know. btw please upvote my answer if it correct, because I need 15 point StackOverflow :(